# Set-Cookie response header doesn't set a cookie (GTM server-side implementation)

Tags: cookies, google-tag-manager, server-side, setcookie, httpcookie

I'm trying to set a cookie with the response from my server-side GTM container.

My setup:

1. Custom HTML tag on client-side GTM:

```
<script>
  fetch('{{sst address}}', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'x-gtm-server-preview': '{{sst preview}}'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "events": [{  
        "event_name": "{{Event}}"
      }]
    })
  });
</script>
```

2. Two requests are being sent:

- [OPTIONS request sreenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J04yE.png)
- [POST request sreenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPsT8.png)

3. Server-Side container set up on the same domain (sing.eventless.org) handles CORS headers + adds 'Set-Cookie' in the response:
   [Response Headers screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjvUO.png)
4. The cookie is visible in the Request explorer but not in the Application tab (also in Safari the cookie is no being created):

- [Cookie visible in the request explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pu1w.png)
- [Lack of Cookie in the Application tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frAY1.png)

5. For the comparison, I set up also a regular Google Tag for GA4 which also sets cookie and then it sets correctly doing exactly the same (Set-Cookie in the response header):
   [cookie set correctly with the GA4 request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnvf9.jpg)

You can replicate it on your side at [eventless.org](https://eventless.org) using Chrome dev tools.

Why the cookie is not being set?

I tried:

- Sending the same request from Postman - **It works there...**
- Changing name/value of the cookie
- Manipulating the SameSite, Domain, Expiration and HttpOnly parameters
- Chaning URLs and paths
- Disabling / enabling cashing

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In the first tag - from the client-side GTM, there should be added credentials:

```html
<script>
  fetch('{{sst address}}', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'x-gtm-server-preview': '{{sst preview}}'
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "events": [{  
        "event_name": "{{Event}}"
      }]
    })
  });
</script>
```